# Split CSV file in Azure Data Factory based on additional headers in file

Tags: csv, split, azure-data-factory

I currently receive csv files in the following format:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
Header1, , ,
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
Header2, , ,
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
Header3, , ,
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
```

The number of rows per header can vary and the Headers can contain any words.

The expected result should be one of:
Option 1: Save headers to additional column in 1 file
File: abc/abc/complete_output

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Header1
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Header1
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Header1
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Header2
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Header3
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Header3
```

Option 2: create different file per header:
File1: abc/abc/Header1

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
```

File2: abc/abc/Header2

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
```

File3: abc/abc/Header3

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
```

The files should either be split from the received format to different files or the header rows should be mapped to an additional column. Can this be done in Azure Data Factory, including Data Flow options? There is no access to a Databricks cluster.

P.S. I know this would be easy with a Python script whatsoever, but I hope to be able to build the complete flow in ADF.

I tried splitting the file based on conditional split. However, this does not work, as this just allows to select rows. This could only be used if (one of) the row values gave an indication about the Header.

No other things seem usable to me.

Edit: added desired output options as asked

Comment: Hi ,
How do you want the output data to look like? Could you please share the expected result?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I provided the expected output options.

Comment: What about header3 in the above example?, Since there are no rows, do you want it to be ignored?

Comment: Also in the sample you have given, both row and column delimiters would be `,`. Is this a typo and the row delimiter is actually `\n`?

Comment: You are right regarding the row delimiter. Headers without row can be ignored or just an empty file, both is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can achieve this with in data factory using variables, loops and conditionals and copy data activity.
- First, read the source file using look up activity without header and random row and column delimiters and **without selecting** `First row as header` option (So that you would get the output as shown in below image.) I have used `;` as column delimiter and `|` as row delimiter and.

[image]

- Now, I have used multiple set variable activities. The `header` activity is to extract the header (col1,col2,col3,col4) from lookup output.

```
@first(array(split(activity('file as text').output.value[0]['Prop_0'],decodeUriComponent('%0A'))))
```

[image]

- `each file` set variable activity to store all the data for each file. I initialized it with `header` variable value.

[image]

- `get first filename` is used to extract the name of first file (header1 in this case) using collection and string functions.

```
@replace(first(skip(array(split(activity('file as text').output.value[0]['Prop_0'],decodeUriComponent('%0A'))),1)),',,,','')
```

[image]

- Now, take the rest of the data (after header1 line), use it as items value in for each loop and then do further processing.

```
@skip(array(split(activity('file as text').output.value[0]['Prop_0'],decodeUriComponent('%0A'))),2)
```

[image]

- Inside for each, I have an `if condition` activity to check if the line is header (to be considered as filename) or not. Accordingly, I have concatenated each line accordingly and used copy data activity as per requirement.

[image]

- The following is the entire pipeline JSON (you can use this directly except that you have to create your datasets).

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "file as text",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "header",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "file as text",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "header",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@first(array(split(activity('file as text').output.value[0]['Prop_0'],decodeUriComponent('%0A'))))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "each file",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "header",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "each file",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@variables('header')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "get first filename",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "each file",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "filename",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@replace(first(skip(array(split(activity('file as text').output.value[0]['Prop_0'],decodeUriComponent('%0A'))),1)),',,,','')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "get first filename",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@skip(array(split(activity('file as text').output.value[0]['Prop_0'],decodeUriComponent('%0A'))),2)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@contains(item(),',,,')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifFalseActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "each row",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "each row",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@concat(variables('each file'),decodeUriComponent('%0A'),item())",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "complete data",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "each row",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "each file",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@variables('each row')",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "create each file",
                                        "type": "Copy",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                            "retry": 0,
                                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "source": {
                                                "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                                "additionalColumns": [
                                                    {
                                                        "name": "req",
                                                        "value": {
                                                            "value": "@variables('each file')",
                                                            "type": "Expression"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "storeSettings": {
                                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                                    "recursive": true,
                                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                                },
                                                "formatSettings": {
                                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                                "storeSettings": {
                                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                                },
                                                "formatSettings": {
                                                    "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                                    "quoteAllText": true,
                                                    "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "enableStaging": false,
                                            "translator": {
                                                "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                                "mappings": [
                                                    {
                                                        "source": {
                                                            "name": "req",
                                                            "type": "String"
                                                        },
                                                        "sink": {
                                                            "type": "String",
                                                            "physicalType": "String",
                                                            "ordinal": 1
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "typeConversion": true,
                                                "typeConversionSettings": {
                                                    "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                                    "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "inputs": [
                                            {
                                                "referenceName": "demo",
                                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "outputs": [
                                            {
                                                "referenceName": "op_files",
                                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                                "parameters": {
                                                    "fileName": {
                                                        "value": "@variables('filename')",
                                                        "type": "Expression"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "change filename",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "create each file",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "filename",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@replace(item(),',,,','')",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "re initialise each file value",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "change filename",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "each file",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@variables('header')",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "for last file within csv",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "additionalColumns": [
                            {
                                "name": "req",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('each file')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "req",
                                    "type": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "String",
                                    "ordinal": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "demo",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "op_files",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "fileName": {
                                "value": "@variables('filename')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "header": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "each file": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "filename": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "each row": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

- For copy data, the source data looks as shown below:

[image]

- The sink of the copy data activity has the following dataset configurations (both source and sink dataset are same in 2 copy data activities):

[image]

- The following are the outputs for each of the file for given sample data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

- If the file ends with data (not header) then the file would be populated as required instead of empty file with just header.

Comment: Thanks Saideep for this extensive and wonderful answer. I'm still struggling with some strange characters in some string values, but generally this solution seems to achieve very well what I'm aiming for! With some tweaking I should be able to make this work. Thanks for showing me the capabilities of ADF in this regard!

Answer (score 0):

If the input dataset is static, considering the second option as requirement then you can go with the following approach:

1. Add Filter transformation after source with expression as : `!startsWith(Col1, 'Header')`
2. Add surrogate key transformation to create the incremental identity column
3. Add conditional split transformation to split the data into three parts having these expressions:

   `stream1`: `Id>=1 && Id<=3`
   `stream2` : `Id==4`
   `stream3 :`  `Default`
4. Use Select transformation to deselect 'Id' column
5. Add sink transformation to load the data to csv file

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since my data is not static this would not work for me, both in the regard of Headers having different names and the row number differing. Still appreciate the effort and showing me this ADF option!